# Using a DataTrigger to start an animation that requires a dynamic value

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, .net-4.5, datatrigger

I have an animation that moves a border (using a render translate transform) to it's width.  This animation needs to be applied to multiple borders, and those borders will vary in width.  So I bound the `Value` property of the animation keyframe to to `ActualWidth` of the border, so it slides out.

Trying to run this code will yield a an exception with the message: `Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.`

Hard coding a value for the `Value` property of the key frame fixes this problem, but then the animation either goes too far, or not far enough.

Here's some example code that shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid >
  <Button Content="Show Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="Button_Click"/>

  <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="260,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
     <Border.Style>
        <Style>
           <Style.Resources>
              <Storyboard x:Key="SlideOut">
                 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=border}"/>
                 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
              <Storyboard x:Key="SlideIn">
                 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
           </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMenuOpen}" Value="True">
                 <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideOut}"/>
                 </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideIn}"/>
                 </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </Border.Style>
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Binding` in `Storyboard`. You can't use **dynamic resource references** or **data binding expressions** to set `Storyboard` or animation property values. That's because everything inside a `Style` must be `thread-safe`, and the timing system must Freeze `Storyboard` objects to make them `thread-safe`. A `Storyboard` cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource references or data `binding` expressions.

**EDIT** This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848381/how-to-access-a-storyboard-within-an-element-resources-from-xaml/15900554#15900554) has the solution.

Comment: Is there a way around that limitation?

Comment: Just now I have updated the answer with new link. It has detailed solution for this kind of problem. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the error your getting is the actual cuase but more of a problem derived from the original problem

try :

```
  <Storyboard x:Key="SlideOut">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
```

It does not make sense to me that you can refer to an object to itself by **ElementName** .