# Coloranimation - animate to default color

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, colors

I'm changing the `TextBlock` color through the trigger, after 5 seconds, I would like to switch the color back to the `TextBlock`'s initial, default color that is defined in the resource dictionary, without defining the color explicitly.

Here is the `TextBlock` style I use:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}" />

            <!--  Go back to initial color  -->
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            BeginTime="0:0:05"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                            To="???" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I mean this line specifically:

```
<ColorAnimation
   BeginTime="0:0:05"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
   To="???" />
```

I have tried setting `To` property to `{x:Null}` markup extension, however the color remains the same.

How can I make it animate to the default color?

---

## edit

Since @Rekshino marked this question as a possible duplicate, I want to state that there is no relation between my question and the question linked by him, hence question might have been misunderstood by him as I haven't asked about `To` property bindings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF animation: binding to the "To" attribute of storyboard animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186933/wpf-animation-binding-to-the-to-attribute-of-storyboard-animation)

Comment: See also the answer to the [WPF Animation “Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669750/wpf-animation-cannot-freeze-this-storyboard-timeline-tree-for-use-across-thread)

Comment: @Rekshino Sorry, I don't see how these questions relate to my problem. I haven't said a word about bindings.

Comment: Actually, that you need is to use `To="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}}"`, but you can't do it in a style, only in control's triggers.